# FileObserver service getting closed by another app

Tags: android

I'm running a FileObserver service that is watching for new files created in a certain folder however whenever I open a separate app that creates said files in that folder, it closes my FileObserver service app (I no longer see it in the Task Manager).  I would like both to run at the same time so that app #2 can create files in the same folder that app #1 is watching.  Any tips as to how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Android has the freedom to terminate any service at any time to reclaim memory. To make it less likely for your service to be chosen for reclaiming memory, [set it to foreground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29).